# Find 10 longest words in a file

Tags: c++, c, string, file, loops

Working on to print the 10 longest words from a file (one word per line).  Words can be printed in any order, and if there are multiple words tied for 10th longest we can decide what to do. The following prints top 1, appreciate any suggestions to build a loop that can iterate and print the next 9.  Assumptions made here, the longest word in the file can be 200 letters and 60 spaces in b/w them. I'm looking to exclude both the assumptions and make it to work more dynamically. Though the following is C like to hear any to write in C++ as well but need to avoid using STL.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 200

int main () {
FILE *fp = fopen("words.txt","r");
char str[60];
char *largest = (char*) malloc (MAX_WORD_LENGTH);
int smallest_len = MAX_WORD_LENGTH, largest_len = 0;

while (fgets (str, 60, fp) != NULL) 
{
    char *temp = strtok(str, "\n");
    while (temp != NULL) 
    {
        if (strlen(temp) > largest_len) 
        {
            strcpy(largest, temp);
            largest_len = strlen(largest);
        }
        temp = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }
}

printf("The largest word in the file is: %s\n", largest);

fclose(fp);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char words[MAX_WORD_COUNT][MAX_WORD_LENGTH]` would be a good place to start, with `MAX_WORD_COUNT` defined as 10.

Comment: Or better yet `typedef struct { char word[MAX_WORD_LEN]; int len } wstats;` and then declare an array `wstats mystats[10] = {{ .word = "" }};` and you can simply iterate over your array, checking `mystats[i].len` and adding/exchanging words as you read through the file.

Comment: How is your file structured? Is it just a file with one word per line?

Comment: Yes it is one word per line.

Comment: Have an array of 10 words (could be array of arrays or could be an array of pointers if you can't guarantee a max size) and an int holding the min size the string would need to be to be allowed into the array (unless the array wasnt full it would be 1 larger than the shortest string). Then whenever you encounter a longer string find the shortest string and replace it with the longer one and update your int variable. If you maintain the array in sorted order, it will be quick to find the element to remove, although that may not be the place to insert the new string to maintain order.

Comment: Also look at the heap data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explicitly state so, but I will assume the file is one word per line based on your sample code.

First, this task is a fairly straightforward one-liner in shell.

`awk '{print length($0), $0}' words.txt | sort -rn | head | awk '{print $2}'`

That will be much faster to write and more robust than rolling your own program. The pipeline prints each word prefixed by its length and a space, sorts the resulting lines numerically in reverse order, takes the first 10, and prints the words without their lengths.

Assuming you do need to write C, here is some advice:

- Unless you have a really strong reason to avoid dynamic allocation, learn how to use [`getline()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline). It handles dynamic allocation for you, which prevents you from needing to choose the size of an array.
- There is no reason to use `strtok()` to remove the newline. A newline will just add one to every length, not changing the result, and you will need to print newlines to report your results anyway.
- Keep you results in an array `char *longwords[10];`. Every time you get a new word, check against everything in `longwords`. If the new word is long enough, replace the shortest word in `longwords` with the new word. [`strdup()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) the new word and [`free()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/free) the existing one as needed.

Comment: Would you mind explaining your advice in C/C++ with a simple code?

Comment: That's a lot less efficient though, it has to sort and store the entire array instead of just the longest entires.

Comment: Yep, try that shell one liner with a 40 GB file and we'll see how it fares against the most trivial solution which just compares each new line with the current top 10 (even without using a max-heap).

Comment: Tell me more about the 40 GB text files you happen to have laying around. There aren't that many words in the English language. But taking you hypothetically, I could scale the shell idea to 40 GB faster than you could implement the "trivial" C solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 200

int main () {
FILE *fp = fopen("words.txt","r");
char str[60];
char *largest = (char*) malloc (MAX_WORD_LENGTH);
int smallest_len = MAX_WORD_LENGTH, largest_len = 0;
int len_temp = MAX_WORD_LENGTH;  // new added code


for (int cnt = 1; cnt <= 10; cnt ++) // new added code
{

    while (fgets (str, 60, fp) != NULL)
    {
        char *temp = strtok(str, "\n");
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            if (strlen(temp) > largest_len && strlen(temp) < len_temp)
            { // here len_temp is for remember the last biggest one length
                strcpy(largest, temp);
                largest_len = strlen(largest);
            }
            temp = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        }
    }
    // new added code
    printf("The %dst word in the file is: %s\n, length is %d", cnt, largest, largest_len);
    len_temp = largest_len;  // remember last largest length
    rewind(fp); // new added code
    largest_len = 0; // new added code
}

fclose(fp);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This seem to be printing the same word ten times.